# Producer-consumer with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I've trying to perform a long-time operation with limited count of consumers (2 for example) in rx style.

The problem is how to be sure that only 2 consumers perform its job at the same time.

Lets we have a Consumer interface:

```
public interface Consumer{
    //Take a lot of time
    Observable<Result> doJob(Task task);

}
```

And queue class:

```
public class Queue {
    public void enqueue(Task task){
        //TODO: enqueue task and do it with limited count of Consumers
    }
}
```

How to organize the work of task queue and consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use schedulers. To limit concurrent work to two tasks:

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));
events.flatMap(x ->
     Observable.fromCallable(() -> process(x))
               .subscribeOn(scheduler))
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```