# How to do proper Producer-Consumer pattern with RX

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How do I do producers-consumers with RX?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768878/producer-consumer-with-rxjava) answer, it uses Java's scheduler that limits the number of concurent OnNext calls on the observer - so I could do something like that in C#, but I am sure that there is a another way to do that. Is there?

Also, I found it weird that standard Subject does not wait for OnNext to end, it just fires immediately.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is all about the scheduler now, but historically subjects used to enforce the serial calls to `.OnNext(...)` - the issue was that if the subject included thread synchronization code that the performance in many non-threaded situations suffered. So subjects where many more efficient, but that allowed concurrent calls to `.OnNext(...)`.

However, you can fix this with some appropriate uses of schedulers or publish calls.

Let's look at some code, starting with these methods:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foo Start");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Foo End");
}

public void Bar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bar Start");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Bar End");
}
```

If I now write this:

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();

subject.Subscribe(u => Foo());
subject.Subscribe(u => Bar());

subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

I get the following:

```
Foo Start
Foo End
Bar Start
Bar End
Foo Start
Foo End
Bar Start
Bar End
```

This code is running on the immediate scheduler - it has to wait for each `.OnNext(...)` call to complete before moving on.

With this code:

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();
var query = subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default);

query.Subscribe(u => Foo());
query.Subscribe(u => Bar());

subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

I now get:

```
Foo Start
Bar Start
Foo End
Foo Start
Bar End
Bar Start
Foo End
Bar End
```

The scheduler now is free to use the thread pool so it schedules calls concurrently.

Now, if we take the same code, but `.Publish()` the query it goes back to the first behaviour:

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();
var query = subject.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Publish();

query.Subscribe(u => Foo());
query.Subscribe(u => Bar());

query.Connect();

subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

And finally, if we go back to the original code, but schedule using an `EventLoopScheduler` then we're using a single background thread so the calls are in series again.

```
var loop = new EventLoopScheduler();
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();
var query = subject.ObserveOn(loop);

query.Subscribe(u => Foo());
query.Subscribe(u => Bar());

subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
subject.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

Comment: yeah, but this is not exactly "consumer", which would process each item once